# FULL bleed video, keep aspect ratio, center, pure javascript

Tags: javascript, math, html5-video, fullscreen, scaling

I would like to have my  element keep its aspect ratio but act as a 'full-bleed' or rather full browser experience. The video should up or down to accommodate the new browser window dimensions, but also be centered in the browser window. At times, some video will get cropped – that's ok with me. I am trying to recreate the background cover CSS property for the video element using pure JS, if that helps you to imagine it. For those who do not know what that is, heres the following:

```
.bkgdCover{
  background: no-repeat center center;
 -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

**The following is my attempt to do the same in pure javascript:**

```
function getWinSize(){
    var wid = 0, hei = 0;

    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight){
        wid = parseInt(window.innerWidth,10);
        hei = parseInt(window.innerHeight,10);
    } else if (document.body){
        wid = parseInt(document.body.offsetWidth,10);
        hei = parseInt(document.body.offsetHeight,10);
    }
    return [wid,hei];
}

this.resize2 = function(){
    fullBleedVideoPlayer();
};

function fullBleedVideoPlayer() {
    var viewport=getWinSize();
    var videoRatio = 1080 / 1920;
    var browserHeight = viewport[0];
    var browserWidth = viewport[1];
    var tmp_windowRatio = viewport[1] / viewport[0];
    if (videoRatio > tmp_windowRatio) {
        tmp_height = Math.round(browserWidth * videoRatio);
        _player.style.width= browserWidth+ "px";
        _player.style.height= tmp_height+ "px";
        _player.style.marginLeft = 0 + 'px';
        _player.style.marginTop = -Math.round((tmp_height - browserHeight) / 2) + 'px';
    } else {
        tmp_width = Math.round(browserHeight * (1 / videoRatio));
        _player.style.width= tmp_width+ "px";
        _player.style.height= browserHeight+ "px";
        _player.style.marginLeft = -Math.round((tmp_width - browserWidth) / 2) + 'px';
        _player.style.marginTop = 0 + 'px';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not reproduce CSS cover. If you can see where I made a mistake or have done the same yourself, I'd love to hear from you. Only pure JS solutions please.

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this except it wasn't completely full screen, it was the background video of a page header which had a height of 450px'ish'. I say ish because I'm using 25vw and it's changing height based on viewport width. I basically wanted the video to stay centered, but how?

HTML

```
<section id="homepage--hero">
  <div class="fullpage-video-wrapper">
    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
      <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
      <!-- doesnt support video -->
      <img src="#" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
    </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#homepage-hero {
  display: block;
  height: 35vw;
  width: 100%;
  position:
  relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullpage-video-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fullpage-video-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
if( $('.fullpage-video-wrapper').length > 0 ) {
    var videoWrapper = $('.fullpage-video-wrapper'),
        videoParentWrapper = $(videoWrapper).parent();

  if($(videoWrapper).height() > $(videoParentWrapper).height() ) {
    var difference = ($(videoWrapper).height() - $(videoParentWrapper).height()) / 4
    $(videoWrapper).css({
      bottom: -parseInt(difference)
    });
  }

  $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(videoWrapper).height() > $(videoParentWrapper).height() ) {
      var difference = ($(videoWrapper).height() - $(videoParentWrapper).height()) / 4
      $(videoWrapper).css({
        bottom: -parseInt(difference)
      });
    }
  });
 }
```

What this does is makes the video stay the same aspect ratio even when resizing window, positions it to the bottom of the homepage-hero, which this caused it to respond well without causing you to see the background color of the video-wrapper, but obviously not centered.
The jQuery is just setting the videowrapper to be offset the difference in height of the video wrapper element height and it's parent elements height. allowing the aspect ratio to stay the same, bleeding the video when needed but allowing it to be centered in it's parents element vertically.

This was super rough, since I was just working on this about an hour ago, so I'm sure theres plenty I need to rework through and get dialed in, but hopefully this helps you along your path, should be the same solution except your doing your height checks on the video element or video wrap element outerHeight and the viewport height.

Comment: btw, I know there is some CSS, but the point I was trying to make was where to position the elements and what to check for. Could easily do this with JS though.